# Cordova-Phonegap - Android, Create many shortcuts linking inside app's sections

Tags: android, cordova, shortcut

I need to create desktop shortcuts that starts my apps and directly enter some section.

Like Whatsapp do it to create a shortcut to a chat with a contact, or some file explorer creates shortcuts to some folder, so when you click it you enter the app and jump to the correct section.

Only found common app shortcut plugins.

Comment: So you know the solution that you will have to add some shortcut plugin, now what is your issue?

Comment: I could not see where to indicate the parameters to call my app in the existings shurtcut plugins, it seems the shurtcut just start the app without indicating witch section to jump to after start. And the other point is how to receive that parameter inside cordova at startup and jump to the section without going to the 'home' screen.